# Alternate between two colors in html table based on alphabetical order

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a table gererated from mysql that shows data like this:
LastNam - Hrs - Total
Anderson - 33 - 1,000
Anderson - 30 - 2,000
Anderson - 23 - 1,000
Ballestero - 12 - 3,000
Ballestero - 05 - 2,000
Castrinsky - 38 - 8,000
Castrinsky - 96 - 6,000

I want to format these lines by having a background color for all the Andersons, no background color for Ballestero and then the same background color for Castrinsky.

Like:
LastNam - Hrs - Total
**Anderson - 33 - 1,000

Anderson - 30 - 2,000

Anderson - 23 - 1,000**

Ballestero - 12 - 3,000
Ballestero - 05 - 2,000
**Castrinsky - 38 - 8,000

Castrinsky - 96 - 6,000**

Very similar to alternate rows on most jquery table plugins or css but not every other line, instead it needs to be every time the previous row is different than the current. I have tried using HeatColor plugin found here: http://www.jnathanson.com/blog/client/jquery/heatcolor/ but having two problems, 1)It shows too many colors, I only need two; 2) it seems to work better with numbers not letters.

Thanks

Comment: If you don't show us your code we can't help you.

Comment: Personally I would do this in the backend. Do you use a server-sided scripting language like PHP? Or do you really need to do it in Javascript?

Comment: I would absolutely do it on the front-end, with Javascript. The backend should only serve the data, not format it.

Comment: Can you post your php that generates the table html?

Comment: Well I think its not wrong for the backend to add classes to rows. In fact I think it would make the output a lot more useable if there is a zebra-like functionality handed from the backend.

Comment: I use PHP and I agree with crush, this should be done at the front end

Comment: Although user762805 has a point, but the zebra like is not every row

Comment: will it really help to show the code? is the regular connection to database, get results and draw a table with it. Is it really necessary?

Comment: It's both a good solution. So I guess you have to do what you do in other similar situations in the project.

Comment: @RafaelGarcia Can you give code or explain **HOW** you are generating the html to be outputted?  I would think if the data is already sorted and you compare the last value with the newest, that would tell you when to change to formatting.

Comment: @crush isn't HTML just formatting? would you use javascript to generate all the HTML? And if you are already looping over the data to generate an HTML table, what is wrong with using php to specify a class? The coloring will still be handled by css.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn No. HTML is not formatting. HTML is structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/AM7QL/1/)

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Hours</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Anderson</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>1,000</td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td>Anderson</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Anderson</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>1,000</td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td>Ballestero</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>3,000</td>
        </tr>          
        <tr>
            <td>Ballestero</td>
            <td>05</td>
            <td>2,000</td>
        </tr>          
        <tr>
            <td>Castrinsky</td>
            <td>38</td>
            <td>8,000</td>
        </tr>          
        <tr>
            <td>Castrinsky</td>
            <td>96</td>
            <td>6,000</td>
        </tr>         
    </tbody>    
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.a1{
    background-color: wheat
}
.a2{
    background-color: gray;
}
```

**JavaScript/jQuery**

```
var $tableBodyRows = $("table tbody tr");
var placeHolder = $("td:eq(0)", $tableBodyRows).text().trim().charAt(0);

$tableBodyRows.each(function(i){
    var letter = $("td:eq(0)", this).text().trim().charAt(0);

    if(letter === placeHolder){
        var c = ($(this).prev().attr('class') !== undefined ? $(this).prev().attr('class') : "a1")
        $(this).addClass(c);
    }else{
        var c = ($(this).prev().attr('class') === "a1" ? "a2" : "a1");
        $(this).addClass(c);
    }

    placeHolder = letter;
});
```

Comment: Chase, have you tried this? I try it in a separate page and it didn't work. I included jquery.

Comment: Try the JSfiddle link near the top. Chances are you need to wrap the actual JavaScript/jQuery code in a `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });` Or for convenience, go here: http://jsfiddle.net/AM7QL/1/

Comment: Chase, how do I change your script to "read" the whole name? I see that you can change the position of the "search" on this line: var placeHolder = $("td:eq(0)", $tableBodyRows).text().trim().charAt(0); But all the combinations I have play with don't do any good. Or how do I change this to analize numbers instead of letters?

Comment: So basically if the full name is the same? Not just the first letter? If so, try taking a look at this updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/AM7QL/2/ - As for the numbers suggestion, which set of numbers are you looking to change it for?

Comment: Gotcha, well give this example a try for the full name: http://jsfiddle.net/AM7QL/2/

Comment: YES!!!! I hope someone looking for this will see your new script as well. Thank a bunch man!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help =) Good luck with everything!

Answer (score 0):

You could drive the heatmap off of a hash code generated from the last name.

Comment: I have check heatmap but it is also more than 2 colors. I only need two

Answer (score 0):

You would basically want to store the lastname you start with and your class, iterate through the loop, when your lastname changes, make your class change...

Here is some psudeocode...  To show the basic idea.  This is assuming you are writing the table dynamically from the server...

```
$prevLastName = (row 1 last name);
$rowClass = 'firstColor';
//start your loop here...
for (...)
{
    //output table row
    echo '<tr id="uniqueIdentifier"  class="rowClass">....</tr>';
    if ($prevLastName === ($currentRowLastName))
    {
        $prevLastName == $currentRowLastName;
        if ($rowClass === 'firstColor')
            $rowClass = 'secondColor';
        else $rowCloass = 'firstColor';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well here is some pseudo code.
Hope it helps :)

```
var lastLastName = "";
var zebra = 0;
foreach (row in rows) {
    if (row.lastName != lastLastName) {
        if (zebra == 1) {
            zebra = 0;
        }
        else {
            zebra = 1;
        }
        lastLastName = row.lastName;
    }

    if (zebra == 0) {
        add an odd class;
    }
    else {
        add an even class;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just check the first letter yourself, instead of using yet another jQuery plugin? It's quite simple, for example:

```
var previousLetter = '';
var styleVariant = 1; // Let's use 1 or 2 to indicate the styling

$('table tr').each(function()
{
    var name = $(this).children('td').first().text();
    var firstLetter = name.charAt(0);

    // If we're at the row where the next letter starts
    if (firstLetter != previousLetter)
    {
        previousLetter = firstLetter;

        // Switching the style to the other variant
        styleVariant = styleVariant == 1 ? 2 : 1;
    }

    $(this).addClass('style' + styleVariant);
});
```

Of course the code isn't that great but I hope you get the gist. I assumed from the question title that you want to alternate for letters, because you mentioned alphabetical order but in case you need to alternate between specific words, it's the same idea.

Comment: I like this. I'm not that familiar with jQuery, so Where will I put the formatting here? In other words, how do I apply this to the table?